# Nginx-Passenger:Does not have any error in log but browser returns error on server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

Installed Nginx and Passenger and have deployed a sample app. Don't know what is going wrong.
Get following statements in nginx error log when using the link - http://www.xyz.com:8080/high_scores/new

```
App 26821 stdout:
[ 2014-02-19 15:33:57.8604 26788/2ab539fa0940 Pool2/SmartSpawner.h:301 ]: Preloader for /home/rails/apps/blog started on PID 26821, listening on unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.26784/generation-0/backends/preloader.26821
App 26951 stdout:
```

I can see the access log recording the hits but nothing appears in error log except the above message.

About the Environment -- Centos 5.x, Rails 4.0.2, Ruby 1.9.3p484

Nginx conf file entry -

```
   server {
      listen 8080;
      server_name www.xyz.com;
      root /home/rails/apps/blog/public;   # <--- be sure to point to 'public'!
      passenger_enabled on;
   }
```

Nginx logs the following messages in error file when starting up .

```
[ 2014-02-19 15:30:57.6547 26785/2b6d8a3dd480 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:538 ]: Options: { 'analytics_log_user' => 'nobody', 'default_group' => 'nobody', 'default_python' => 'python', 'default_ruby' => '/home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/wrappers/ruby', 'default_user' => 'nobody', 'log_level' => '0', 'max_pool_size' => '6', 'passenger_root' => '/home/rails/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p484/gems/passenger-4.0.37', 'passenger_version' => '4.0.37', 'pool_idle_time' => '300', 'temp_dir' => '/tmp', 'union_station_gateway_address' => 'gateway.unionstationapp.com', 'union_station_gateway_port' => '443', 'user_switching' => 'true', 'web_server_passenger_version' => '4.0.37', 'web_server_pid' => '26784', 'web_server_type' => 'nginx', 'web_server_worker_gid' => '99', 'web_server_worker_uid' => '99' }
[ 2014-02-19 15:30:57.6610 26788/2ab5380784c0 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:643 ]: PassengerHelperAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.26784/generation-0/request
[ 2014-02-19 15:30:57.6663 26793/2b3acb8e1d70 agents/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:321 ]: PassengerLoggingAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.26784/generation-0/logging
[ 2014-02-19 15:30:57.6666 26785/2b6d8a3dd480 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:728 ]: All Phusion Passenger agents started!
```

Did not find any specific error in the log... but then the browser too doesn't show up anything.

One more observation is that when i run the following command

> `sudo passenger-status 11298`

get an error -

> `/usr/bin/env: ruby_executable_hooks: No such file or directory`

I am new to this environment so any type of suggestions to troubleshoot will help.

Comment: "is not working" - sure don't tell us what the actual error is, let us try and guess it, it's far more fun!

Comment: Have tried rephrasing the question slightly. I could see the same messages logged when i configured passenger with apache earlier. So my guess is it is an issue with passenger configuration or web server and  passenger conf.

Comment: Try Passenger Standalone instead of Passenger for Apache: http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Standalone.html

Comment: Please can you say the details - "browser returns error on server" is that a 502, 404, etc.